# Create dialog confirm in server site ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, dialog, confirm

I want to create a dialog confirm in ASP.NET.

I'm doing it with this code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;
    
    string strconfirm = "<script>if(!window.confirm('Are you sure?')){window.location.href='Default.aspx'}</script>";
    CSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", strconfirm, false);
        
    if (the condition to yes clicked)
    {
        // do something ....
    }
    else 
    {
        // do something else ....
    }
}
```

How can I get the yes / no condition in this case?

Thanks for reading my post

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. Your code behind NEVER interacts with the user. Your code behind ONLY interacts with the web page, and ONLY does so WHILE the page is making the round trip.

Before a post back? You have this setup:

[image]

You do NOT have this:

[image]

And you do not have this either:

[image]

So, when a user clicks a button - this occurs CLIENT side. The page - whole web page is sent up to the server - and THEN your code interacts with the web page - NOT the user!!!

so, you click on a button - (browser). The page THEN starts the all important round trip. Like this:

[image]

the page travels up to server,

You now have this:

[image]

Now and THEN your code behind runs. When done, your code behind MUST finish, else the page stays stuck up on the server side. When done, the whole page page makes the trip down back to the browser. And THEN the page is re-displayed and THEN any js code can run.

So when done? Your page makes the trip back down to the browser like this:

[image]

And only AFTER the page makes that trip, can the browser display what your code behind changed. So your code behind NEVER interacts with the user, but in fact can ONLY interact with the web page and ONLY do so for the short time that the web page is up on the server.

So, how can you pop a dialog and get a yes/no answer? Well, you require the dialog to run and launched client side. And based on the user hitting ok, or cancel, you can THEN have a code stub run.

So you can say have code that flows like this:

```
ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;

    string strconfirm = "<script>if(!window.confirm('Are you sure?')){window.location.href='Default.aspx'}</script>";
    CSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", strconfirm, false);

 Function OkCode - runs on user click or seleciton.


 Function Cancel Code - runs on user click of cancel button.
```

So, you need 3 code stubs. One to inject the script that will pop the dialog. And then the ok or cancel button in that script/dialog can THEN launch the server side code again. This will of course require that round trip (as all server side button event code does).

There are a few short cuts. Say I have a standard asp.net button, and I want a confirm dialog? Well, you can do this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete"
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete record');"/>
```

The above works, since the confrim in js returns true or false and that will prevent the button code (code behind server side) from running.

You could of course have a script that you call from code behind. Keep in mind that your register script quite much has to be the LAST thing you do and inject into that page before it travels back down to the client. The page dispays and THEN your script you added THEN runs!

You could say then have two buttons on your form - hide them. And then have a js dialog that clicks either button based on what you pass.

So, say we build that function. We will pass it the question/text, and then say two buttons (one for ok click, and one for cancel click). And you could set the style of those buttons as display:none. This will still not get you a server side if/then result from that dialog. So, you have to quite much in near ALL cases break your code out to 3 seperate parts.

The part that triggers the dialog.

And the two buttons that run code behind stubs based on the choice(s) the user makes. In other words, adding the dialog by script would STILL require you to have TWO separate code stubs behind to run (the one for ok, and the one for cancel). You simply can't pop a dialog server side and wait. That would result in the web page being stuck up on the server in the above round trip concept. That round trip dialog MUST be absorbed into your mind - without that model of how the round trip works, then you make mistakes in your design assumptions - and thus your question which is actually not really possible to achieve.

You could create a generalized dialog that you set the text in code behind along with your register script idea. but the button choices and code it runs would also have to be setup in that register script, and you would still require two separate code behind stubs (one for cancel, and one for ok). So it would be possible to setup something that requires you to NOT have special code in each page, but you would require a js function routine you build up, and you would have to supply it the name of the two code stubs, and then that js routine could send a __DoPostBack passing the choice made.

But even again, note how you need separate routines, since that web page is sitting on the users desktop, and your code behind is not waiting for a dialog, but in fact a WHOLE PAGE post back.

So just keep mind that code behind does not interact with the user - it ONLY interacts with the web page, and ONLY does so during that short round trip and in fact ONLY during the time that the web page is up on the server, and your code behind runs and then is finished. And THEN the web page starts that trip back to the client side - the page is re-loaded, changes you made are displayed, and THEN the js in that page starts to run again.